# Javascript empty function and prototype usage

Tags: javascript

```
MathUtils = function() {};

MathUtils.prototype.sum = function(number1, number2) {
        return number1 + number2;
}

MathUtils.prototype.substract = function(number1, number2) {
    return number1 - number2;
}
```

The above is a code snippet that I am currently testing using Jasmine. Can someone please help me understand what is the significance of Line no 1? The file name is MathUtils.js. Also it would be really helpful if I could get a brief on what .prototype is.

Comment: Just `MathUtils.sum = ...` and `MathUtils.substract = ...`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The significance of line 1 is that it creates an Object instance.
Prototype is the chain that mimics inheritance in JavaScript.